Efficiently compute distance of linearly transformed points
I have a set of points $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then I apply the linear transformation $y_i = A^T x_i$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$, with $m<n$. The columns of $A$ are linearly independent.
Say that we need to compute the distances between each pair $y_i$ for a set of such linear transformations $A_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Is there a way in which this can be done efficiently? In particular, is there a way to compute the pairwise distances $||y_i - y_j||$ from the distances $||x_i - x_j||$? If the answer for the general case is no, then is there an efficient way to compute the distances when the columns of $A_k$ are orthonormal?
